# Canvas#drawBitmap is thwarting Canvas#drawPath in SurfaceView

Tags: android, path, bitmap, draw, surfaceview

I have a `SurfaceView` that must draw a path below, between or above two bitmaps.  I'm animating the drawing of the path such that it will appear to grow to full size.  This code works **providing** I don't draw the bitmaps.

The Bitmaps are specified (in `onLayout(...)`, to get the `View` dimensions) like this:

```
mFrontBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) width, (int) height, mConfig);
Canvas temp = new Canvas(mFrontBitmap);
temp.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, Mode.CLEAR);
```

(I'm wiping them so as not to leave anything to chance.)  Then the draw code inside the `SurfaceView` thread's run method is

```
if(mCurrentLayer==Layer.BACK) {
    //draw path
    if(mPath!=null)
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}

canvas.drawBitmap(mBackBitmap, 0, 0, null);

if(mCurrentLayer==Layer.MIDDLE) {
    //draw path
    if(mPath!=null)
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}

canvas.drawBitmap(mFrontBitmap, 0, 0, null);

if(mCurrentLayer==Layer.FRONT) {
    //draw path
    if(mPath!=null)
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}
```

With the two `drawBitmap` lines commented out, the animation renders fine.  With them in, I see nothing till the animation is complete, and then the path is rendered (in its entirety) directly to one of the bitmaps.  I'm at something of a loss.  I have looked at the LunarLander sample and it is rendering a background bitmap, so this is clearly something `SurfaceView` *can* do, but for me it won't.  What could it be?

Answer (score -1):

To draw each time you want the content of the bitmaps you may use this each time you do the    canvas.drawPath(...):

```
mpath.invalidate();
```

(I'm assuming the mpath is the view/surfaceview).

So it would look like this:

```
if(mCurrentLayer==Layer.BACK) {
    //draw path
    if(mPath!=null) {
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        mPath.invalidate();
    }
}

canvas.drawBitmap(mBackBitmap, 0, 0, null);

if(mCurrentLayer==Layer.MIDDLE) {
    //draw path
    if(mPath!=null) {
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        mPath.invalidate();
    }
}

canvas.drawBitmap(mFrontBitmap, 0, 0, null);

if(mCurrentLayer==Layer.FRONT) {
    //draw path
    if(mPath!=null) {
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        mPath.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: `mPath` is actually a `Path` object; there is no `invalidate()` method in `Path`.  The `SurfaceView` has a `SurfaceHolder` and rather than drawing from `onDraw()` like other `View`s you run a thread that calls `Canvas canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas()` which lets you draw on a `Canvas` object; then at the end you call `mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)` which (supposedly) puts the canvas to the surface.  As such you don't need to `invalidate()` but thanks anyway.